# Is this grammatically correct: "...of, and the NOUN to, .. NOUN"?

Tags: grammaticality

I would be glad if you let me know if something similar was already answered somewhere.

Is this grammatically correct?

"The researcher's aim was to study **the living conditions of and the medical treatment given to** the inpatients of a particular hospital."

Or:
"The researcher's aim was to study **the living conditions of, and the medical treatment given to,** the inpatients of a particular hospital."

I realise this ***of, and ... to,*** might sound unnatural and may be expressed in a less complex way, but wanted to inquire whether the sentence is grammatically incorrect.

Thanks!

Comment: In fact, both sentences seem to be correct, but separated by commas, makes it more readable.

Comment: Such constructions are normal, and the commas are necessary.

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelHarvey! Is there any chance you know whether such constructions have a specific name?

Comment: Thank you, @RamPillai!

Comment: Using two commas makes the second phrase appear to be a "parenthetical", and hence an "afterthought" of sorts.